Can I use Microsoft 365 for only some email addresses, and continue using the corporate email server with other addresses?
I use Plesk to manage my hosting.
I have more than 30 corporate email addresses like xxxxx@mydomain.com of which, some of them are more relevant.
I would like to use Microsoft 365 with some of them only, but I wonder if I can keep using my server email with some other addresses.
My doubt is if I can keep using my server email system, even though I'm going to change MX records in order to use MS 365 email.
(Sorry for my English)

In general, if you're using only one domain (e.g., __@example.com) to receive email at, then the MX records would need to correspond to that domain. If you're using two separate domains, or a domain and a subdomain however, then that might be possible.

That depends on the mail transfer agent. For example, using Postfix you could set up routing rules to selectively redirect mail to another MX, in this case M365. Or the other way round (M365 -> your server) could be possible as well. So that depends on what is running on your server, and whether you have access to configuration options.
